# Symfony frontend framework

Tags: angularjs, ember.js, reactjs, symfony

I'm using **Symfony 3.0** and want to choose a frontend framework that better fits with Symfony.

Some options are **ReactJs**, **AngularJS**, **EmberJs**, **Ionic**, etc ...

**Requirements**

1. One requirement, is that I don't want to put more complexity on my application(like server-side rendering or a js compiler).
2. Another requirement is that it provides an easy way to handle the form submission(like using $form->handleRequest() )

What lead me to choose a frontend framework is the complexity added when you have to manage nested collections that have some form components that are loaded via ajax(breaking the forms *dom name* symfony convention)

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need a "framework". If you want to do more than basic dynamic enhancements, then some more opinionated frontend might be useful. If all you want to do is add some minor UX improvements, you'll probably have an easer time just using JS and some minor libraries. (The classic answer there is jQuery, but you usually don't need jQuery these days.)

Second, the current "best tools" for frontend work require JS build steps. While even React and Angular can be shoehorned into single JS files that you write and maintain directly, with links for the library/framework code to CDNs, this is possibly the most difficult way to go about it. You are probably better served by getting familiar with using tools such as Webpack, Babel, Typescript, or competing tools which do the same job.

Third, my personal, *general*, recommendation for a complex frontend is to use Webpack and Babel to build an application using React for the view. I think using React properly leads to highly maintainable software.

React is not a framework, and doesn't include anything for sending ajax requests or forms. It is a view library, which means that it's an option to simply render a normal html form with a submit button. Without significant experience with Angular and other frameworks, all I can say is that you probably can do that there too, but they often provide specific ajax flows as well, which should be fairly simple to deal with on your server.

Comment: Great answer. I'd choose React too, just because it's not really a framework, and would take less impact in the future if I choose to take it off. The reason I want to use a framework is that I'm afraid that this UI operations that I'm doing with pure Jquery right, would get more complex in the future, and I'll want to reuse then too; +1 point to React?

Comment: If you do your operations using a framework, then they will be less reusable, since they would only work when you are using that framework. For example, if you use fetch (and the polyfill for now) and some functional wrappers, that code will work with React, Riot, plain javascript, and potentially with some frameworks as well. On the other hand, if you were to use Angular's (1.x) http service (a non-current example from memory), then that code will only work with Angular.

Comment: I realize I didn't actually the touch the topic of Symfony specific integration. Symfony (2 or 3) is highly agnostic of the frontend. It has built-in handlers for it's own generated forms, but it's a helper, not a requirement. You can easily just parse JSON requests and work from there, or read GET/POST params directly.